# How to model recursive calls in UML

Tags: python, recursion, uml

I want to model function calls of my application (written in Python) in UML and I've two problems.

First is that I've tried to draw sequence diagram, but it is for modeling method calls of objects and my application is written procedurally, i.e. the only objects I actually have are instances of types from libraries I use (e.g. html5lib).

The 2nd issue is that there are some recursive calls, which I need to model on the UML diagram and sequence diagram seems to be bad solution for this.

Which of UML diagrams should I use then? And how to model recursive calls, like in function below?

```
def node_preprocessing(node):
    global tags_remove, tags_special
    if node.nodeType==3: # Text node
        return preprocessing(node.wholeText)
    if node.nodeType==1 and node.tagName not in tags_remove: # Tag node
        if node.tagName in tags_special:
            return tags_special[node.tagName](node)
        return convert_tag(node) % u"".join(map(node_preprocessing, node.childNodes))
    return u""
```

On the other hand I do not want to show exactly everything what happens in this function. Only what it calls (itself, preprocessing(text), convert_tag(node)) and in what order.

ps. *tags_special* is a *dict* of lambda functions. I do not need calls of them modeled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily model recursive calls. You don't even need to have objects to use sequence diagrams. But if you are interested only in called methods and their sequence, I think the best fit would be the communication diagram http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_diagram . Recursive calls can be modeled using iteration (*). In sequence diagrams recursion can be modeled using loop partitions.

Answer (score 0):

A UML statechart diagram might be a good fit.  [This example](http://www.agilemodeling.com/style/stateChartDiagram.htm) has some reflexive arrows that might be useful for showing recursion.